# Why merfolk do not evolve dorsal fin?

Tags: evolution, anatomy, merfolk

Dorsal fin helps to stabilize the creature in water much like rocket with fins, how could such a cunning apex marine predator be missing a dorsal fin? Also how do they compensate for it during high speed chase?

Note: merfolk enjoys drive hunting which demands sudden burst of speed as well as making sharp turns.

Comment: Some species of whales don't have dorsal fins either. How can you explain that?

Comment: @a4android: and how fast do they swim?

Comment: I am sorry but this question is silly, and displays a huge lack of understanding how evolution works. Traits do not pop into existence because they would be useful to future generations. That is not at all how evolution works. If evolution had done what is best for the future of a species, then humans would not have had a genetic deficiency that makes us susceptible to Scurvy from lack of vitamin C instead of creating it in our bodies like so many other species, nor would we have a retina that is backwards. This sort of thing does is **not** a problem that needs solving. It is already solved.

Comment: The answer to the question: "Why did merfolk not evolve a dorsal fin?". Answer: because the necessary mutations just never happened.

Comment: @MichaelK: I admit that I'm not familiar with the concept of evolution but may I ask you a question: do dog evolve from wolves?

Comment: @user6760 Then you need to read up on [evolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolution) a little bit before you ask a question about evolution. Dogs have become a separate family from wolves though selective breeding by humans, yes.

Comment: @MichaelK I apologize for having to do this, but this is one of my pet peeves. "The answer to the question: "Why did merfolk not evolve a dorsal fin?". Answer: because the necessary" selection pressures are absent or ineffective. Evolution isn't driven by mutations, but by natural selection. Mutations play only a minor role except in how selection pressures act on them.

Comment: @a4android Yeah well without the mutation **existing** in the first place there can be a figurative ton of pressure and it will still not produce a new trait. And since mutations are not infinite but a finite quantum, there can actually be **zero** mutations in the direction of a dorsal fin.

Comment: @MichaelK I recommend you read the Wikipedia article on evolution. It's the selection pressures that produce the changes in traits not mutations. As I said mutations only play a minor role, and I do mean *minor*. The combinations for traits are usually present in a population's genetics. Selection pressures force them to be expressed.

Comment: @a4android Minor but **necessary** role. Also the pressure must be such that the ones with a budding trait gives so much better fitness that the trait does not become diluted by being bread with individuals that do not have the butting trait. The answer to the question is: the mutations were not strong enough to be expressed and/or the pressure was not enough to increase fitness enough for individuals with a budding trait to be further expressed.

Comment: @Michaelk: maybe the k9 example is deep so try this: dart frog don't have the genes to make their own poison, they acquire it from their diet and become immune... this is example of how evolution at its finest not because mutations just happened necessarily.

Comment: @user6760 That comment was a complete [Non Sequitur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_sequitur_(logic)).

Answer (score 2):

**Hands**

Dorsal fins largely function to stabilize against rolling. A Merfolk's hands can accomplish that function and much more. Being on wrist joints, they can pivot to allow the creature whatever degree of control they wish. Additionally, as they're attached to the useful appendages called arms, they can also be used for propulsion and other tasks as well.

Comment: to achieve streamline in water I thought it would be best for merfolk to keep their arms by the sides or do the superman pose... except they don't clench their fists.

Comment: @user6760 If you're going for speed, yes. A remarkable amount of control can be achieved via small hand movements, especially if there's webbing between the fingers. Just like rockets, where the control surfaces are tiny compared to the actual vehicle.

Comment: @user6760 might I recommend checking out people who swim with monofins and mermaid tails? They have their hands out and to a point. Like the A in YMCA, but with the palms downward and not together.

Answer (score 1):

An issue I thought of was placement. A dolphin's dorsal fin is kinda in the space behind where the rib cage ends. On humans that would be the small of the back. If you ever watch someone try to do a dolphin kick or swim with a monofin, they need to have a good sense of flow throughout the body. Putting a dorsal fin there may make the back stiffer and impede that.

A dolphin is very hydrodynamically shaped and the dorsal fin is basically the highest part of its body. I don't know if a human would be optimally shaped for using a dorsal fin, unless *maybe* it was really large. I still think that would be detrimental since that could also increase water resistance.

Comment: You may want to clarify/re-word your answer. I initially thought you were answering on how a human-shaped creature would have a dorsal fin, not how a human-shaped creature is bad for a dorsal fin.

Comment: @Andon Thats fair. I've elaborated on the first part as to why that placement isn't very good.